# mysql ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; is not reflecting on rails rake db:seed

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

After executing

```
ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

in mysql when I run

`rake db:seed` - mysql id number doesn't start with value 1 though the table is empty initially. Why is it so?

Comment: Is it MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: try adding environment before running seed `RAILS_ENV=production rake:seed` or `RAILS_ENV=development rake:seed`